# Showing surjection and morphism

Tags: ring-theory

Lets say I have 2 matrices,
matrix A$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\                                                  d & e & f \\                                                      g & h & i \end{array}\right]$$
and matrix B $$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc} j & k & l\\ m & n & o\\ p & q & r \end{array}\right]$$

How do I show that the mapping $$\theta: A \to B $$ is a morphism and surjective?

To show that the mapping $\theta$ is a morphism, do I just need to show that $$\theta(A+B)=....=\theta(A)+\theta(B)$$ and 
$$\theta(AB)=....=\theta(A)\theta(B)$$, is that it for a morphism?

How would I show surjection?

If I was trying to show that a quotient ring $$A/B is isomorphic to C, where c is some other matrix ring, could I just show that B is the kernel of A and then just show morphism and surjection?

Comment: What do you mean by those matrices being rings?  Matrices of the form of $A$ are not closed under matrix multiplication.  The first row third column need not always be $0$.

Comment: Sorry ignore the rings bit. Amended

Comment: But, now it doesn't make sense to have a homomorphism between just two matrices.

Comment: how about now? If we were speaking hypothetically, is the method correct?

Comment: I think what you are trying to ask is this:  Suppose $R$, $S$, and $T$ are matrix rings, i.e. sets of matrices that are closed under multiplication and addition.  Then to show that $\theta:R\to S$ is a morphism you need to only show $\theta(A+B)=\theta(A)+\theta(B)$ and $\theta(AB)=\theta(A)\theta(B)$ for all $A,B\in R$.  Additionally, to show that $R/S\cong T$ you need only show that there is a morphism $\phi:R\to T$ with $\ker(\phi)=S$.  The answer to both is "yes".

Comment: @joejohnson126 that is what I meant, thanks. Also how can I show surjection between R and T?

Comment: To show surjectivity, you have to take some $B\in T$ and show that some $A\in R$ maps to it, $\phi(A)=B$.  The way you show this would differ depending on exactly what $R$ and $T$ are.

Answer (score 1):

To be pedantic, you should say "elements of ring $A$ have the form" and not matrix $A$. $A$ is a collection of matrices; not a matrix in its own right. Same for $B$.

Surjection is fairly easy. Given an element of $B$, what element of $A$ maps to i?. You're 90% of the way there considering how you phrased the question.

Yeah, you would need to need to show $\theta(a+b)=\theta(a)+\theta(b)$, and$\theta(ab)=\theta(b)\theta(b)$. This is just some computation. Tedious but not difficult.

You can't say $A/B$. It doesn't make sense because $B$ is not a sub-ring of $A$. You can use the first(?) isomorphism theorem and say $A/\text{ker}(\theta)$ is isomorphic to the image of $A$ under $\theta$,usually denoted  $\text{im}(A)$ or  $\theta(A)$. Now what is $\text{im}(A)$? If you have proven surjectivity, then $\text{im}(A)=B$.

Thus $A/\text{ker}(A) \simeq B$.

EDIT: The OP  originally had very specifically structured matrices. Some of what I posted is now wrong as the OP changed the $A$ and $B$ to be as general as possible. Before, A and B had a very certain formed that implied a unique $\theta$ and the problem was actually very concrete.

Comment: Would you be so kind to give me an example of how to prove surjection please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question has entirely changed since you edited it; to the point where I can't directly prove surjectivity.

Comment: ok, fair enough